# What does ??? mean in iOS

Tags: ios, stack-trace, crash-log

I'm new to iOS, and the simple app I'm trying to code crashed with the following:

```
2014-07-18 22:21:19.006 Weather Client[1191:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] was unable to load a nib named "WeatherClientViewController"'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017ec1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0156b8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017ebfbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x003497d6 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 505
    4   UIKit                               0x00349e9d -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    5   UIKit                               0x0034a0d3 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    6   UIKit                               0x0034a5d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    7   UIKit                               0x0026a267 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    8   UIKit                               0x0026a5ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    9   UIKit                               0x0026a86b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    10  UIKit                               0x002753c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    11  Weather Client                      0x000023eb -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 715
    12  UIKit                               0x0022514f -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
    13  UIKit                               0x00225aa1 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1810
    14  UIKit                               0x0022a667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    15  UIKit                               0x0023ef92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    16  UIKit                               0x0023f555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    17  UIKit                               0x0022c250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x037e1f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x037e1a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01767ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x017679db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0179268c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x017919d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x017917eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  UIKit                               0x00229d9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    26  UIKit                               0x0022bf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  Weather Client                      0x00002e3d main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e33701 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

What I was wondering is what is the significance of ??? in line 29.  I've tried googling, and the only references to ? were to do with ternary operators.  Can anyone tell me what ??? means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing left on the call stack:

```
27  Weather Client                      0x00002e3d main + 141
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e33701 start + 1
29  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
```

Frame 28 is where `start` (the runtime startup code) called your program's `main` function. Nothing (in your program's lifetime) happens before this.

For whatever reason, there is some value `1` on the stack before that first real frame, and the stack-walking code obviously doesn't know what function is at the (invalid) address `1`.

Really nothing to worry about.